# Conditional merging elements of python list

Tags: python

Lets say I've the following list,
['x','alpha','bravo','charlie','x','jack','x','mango','norway']

And I would want the following output
['x','alpha,bravo,charlie','x','jack','x','mango,norway']

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the pattern that any items adjacent to one another should be joined as long as they aren't an x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

items = ["x", "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "x", "jack", "x", "mango", "norway"]

print([",".join(group) if key else "x" for key, group in groupby(items, key=lambda i: i != "x")])
```

Output:

```
['x', 'alpha,bravo,charlie', 'x', 'jack', 'x', 'mango,norway']
>>>
```

Comment: This is better than mine! Didn't know about itertools.groupby

Comment: If there are several "x" in a row, you delete all but one of them. Why?

Comment: @HeapOverflow That's true, `itertools.groupby` does behave in this way. I wonder if it's a case the OP needs to take into account? In that case this solution would not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern I described is correct, try something like this:

```
mylist = ['x','alpha','bravo','charlie','x','jack','x','mango','norway']
mynewlist = []
for i in mylist:
    if len(mynewlist) == 0 or i == 'x' or mynewlist[-1] == 'x':
        mynewlist.append(i)
    else:
        mynewlist[-1] += ("," + i)
mynewlist
```